# Addition on location

Tags: rascal

Is there a way to add 2 location with a specific line and column with each other?

Something like:

```
|project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(962,10,<39,2>,<39,12>) + |project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(975,53,<40,2>,<40,55>);
```

With as outcome:

```
 |project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(962,66,<39,2>,<40,55>)
```

I am currently working with AST's and I want to have a selection of a block but I couldn't find how so I tried to add every statement's location but that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Paul's answer, this also handles the typical case, where there is a "gap" (probably whitespace) between the second location and the first:

```
loc add(loc s, loc r) {
    res = s;
    res.end = r.end;
    adjust = 0;
    if (s.offset + s.length < r.offset) {
        adjust = r.offset - (s.offset+s.length);
    }
    res.length = s.length + r.length + adjust;
    return res;
}
```

You definitely have to be careful with this, though -- there are a bunch of cases and possible error conditions that this doesn't handle (e.g., locations overlap, locations passed in in the wrong order, locations are actually from different files). It should handle just "merging" locations for two adjacent constructs, though.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting observation. Addition on locations as you need is at the moment not provided as built-in operation (but we might consider to add it).

As an aside: addition on location and string **is** supported:

```
rascal>|project://MyProject/src| + "MyClass.java";
loc: |project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|
```

If you look at [the description of Locations](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/Location.html) you find all the ingredients to build addition on locations yourself. For instance, this would do:

```
loc add(loc s, loc r) {
    res = s;
    res.end = r.end;
    res.length = s.length + r.length;
    return res;
}
```

This will give you:

```
rascal>add(|project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(962,10,<39,2>,<39,12>),   |project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(975,53,<40,2>,<40,55>));
loc: |project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(962,63,<39,2>,<40,55>)
```

The above solution falls short in handling these case where the locations overlap (but I did not want to obfuscate the solution too much).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above answer was edited after a suggestion by http://stackoverflow.com/users/2382373/mark-hills